# Is this correct? Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\log\left(\frac{n(n+1)!}2\right)}$

Tags: summation

Is this correct?
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\log\left(\frac{n(n+1)!}2\right)}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\log n!}\approx\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log (n)-n}$$
Since the integral below does not converge, then the sum does not also converge.
$$\int_2^\infty\frac{\mathrm dn}{n\log(n)-n}=\log(\log(n)-1)\Big|_2^\infty$$

Comment: No, any series can be bounded above by a divergent series. For example, $\sum \frac 1/n^2 < \sum 1$.

Comment: What are you indicating with $\frac{n(n+1)!}2$ is $\frac n 2 (n+1)!$?

Comment: @QuangHoang how do you think should I show the convergence of the original sum?

Comment: @gimusi how are the two different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed you can't conclude for divergence with that bound (we need "our series" $\ge$ "divergent series").

By [**Stirling's approximation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we have that

$$\frac{n(n+1)!}2 \sim \frac12n(n+1)\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sim \frac k {e^n}n^{n+\frac52}$$

and therefore

$$\log\left(\frac{n(n+1)!}2\right)\sim \left(n+\frac52\right)\log n+\log k-n\sim n\log n$$

then refer to limit comparison test and show that

$$\frac{\frac1{\log\left(\frac{n(n+1)!}2\right)}}{\frac1{n\log n}}=\frac{n\log n}{\log\left(\frac{n(n+1)!}2\right)} \to L$$

Comment: @Euleroid It is a constant.

Comment: Forgive me again, how do I use the test? What do I compare?

Comment: @Euleroid Are not you aware about Limit Comparison Test? Refer to [LCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear what $b_n$ i will use.

Comment: @Euleroid The evaluation by Stirling help to guess that $b_n=1/n\log n$. Now to forlmalize we need to take the limit $a_n/b_n$.

Comment: @Euleroid As you can see it is a very effective test since we can at first estimate and then just compare the limit without serach for correct inequalities.

Comment: Thank you! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Euleroid You are welcome! Keep LCT in mind! Bye